# P&T Assets Error Creating Subfolders : Invalid Assets Source Path

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, path

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here. But for some reason, when I try and create a new subfolder, I get the following: "Invalid Assets source path". I checked and the parent folder has CHMOD of 777. I'm running Assets 2.0.4 and EE 2.6.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the actual Server Path setting is incorrect; not just a permissions issue. Ensure that it’s correct and then try updating Assets’ indexes for that directory.